# System.out.print: why the output is not sent to console?

Tags: java, netbeans, system.out

There is java jar-application, code contains several operators like `System.out.print("something to print")`. Console (like DOS window) is created by `cmd.exe`, and then `java -jar myFile.jar` is performed. I wonder why the output from `System.out.print` is not seen on the console? When this application runs inside netbeans, all output is seen on the netbeans console, but not seen when runs on the 'DOS the console'.

Thanks in advance
PS Sorry that I don't know the name for console created with `cmd.exe`

Comment: It's called commandprompt.

Comment: give full example of your code

Comment: Maksym Pecheniuk, the full code is abot 5k (in two classes). Is it normal to include it?

Comment: Everything has got working after 'clean and rebuild'. I think the old version was saved in jar-file. I thought that netbeans rebuilds and saves the project with each compiling.

Comment: Thanks everybody who answered and commented. Everything works!

Answer (score 0):

It is command prompt. and try running this command.

> java -cp myFile.jar YourFileName

replace YourFileName with java file with main method in that jar file (without extension). hope it will works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` and `System.err` can both be redirected to point to any PrintStream you want.

See the Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut(java.io.PrintStream))

> **public static void setOut(PrintStream out)**
>
> Reassigns the "standard" output stream.
>
> First, if there is a security manager, its checkPermission method is
>   called with a RuntimePermission("setIO") permission to see if it's ok
>   to reassign the "standard" output stream.
>
> **Parameters:**
>       out - the new standard output stream Throws:
>       SecurityException - if a security manager exists and its checkPermission method doesn't allow reassigning of the standard
>   output stream. Since:
>       JDK1.1
>
> **See Also:**
>       SecurityManager.checkPermission(java.security.Permission), RuntimePermission